# std::map< K, std::vector<E>> allocation

Tags: c++, caching, stl

I have buckets keyed by K with elements of type E. Initially we don't know what the keys K are so we can't pre-allocate with known K values. You can move arbitrary elements to the start of the bucket after they are filled hence the use of a list for the container.

```
template <typename K, typename E>
std::map< K, std::list<E> > buckets;
```

What is the best way to insert items into the buckets? Both K and E will likely be 32 bit unsigned integers in practice. K should have cardinality of less than 256 elements. E could hundreds of millions but all will be unique.

Comment: Bah typo in the title. I would be happy to hear answers for std::vector too and experiment with converting them into a list at the end after buckets are filled.

Comment: My biggest issue is performance. I don't want to thrash the OS doing mallocs, and I would like the resulting list to have some cache locality.

Comment: This sounds like a premature optimization question. You have a perceived problem of thrashing OS memory and lacking locality of reference, but no measurements to back up any of it. I would suggest trying the simplest thing you can code up, then measure the performance, and see if it is inadequate.

Comment: I intend to benchmark the answers and recommend the fastest. High performance use case so being near the optimal cache/malloc efficiency is a requirement not a nicety.

Comment: Looks remarkably like a multimap.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm not certain that he could move around the elements within an equal range of a multimap, though.

Comment: @das Oh, yes, I missed that requirement.

Comment: How is this going to be used?  For example, does the order of the elements sharing the same key matter?  Or are you simply wanting to test it like a `set`, in which case `multimap` may suite you well?  Do you know how big E will be before populating it?  To clarify, you want to optimize for removal at arbitrary locations and insertions at the beginning, yes?  How often will you be doing that?  I need more information about your use case before I can give suggestions about how to optimize.

Comment: See the naive solution I posted. Use case should be similar.

Comment: @mikebob E is the index of an element in an array for my use case, so at creation of the buckets we should know the cardinality of E. Later on there is a post processing step where elements will be taken from the middle of the buckets and appended to the front. At most half the elements could be shifted to the front, but there will only be one pass over the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution just inserting not converting to a list.

```
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  size_t size = 100000000;
  size_t *arr = (size_t *)malloc(sizeof(size_t) * size);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = (size_t)rand() % 30;
  }
  system("/bin/date +%s%M");
  std::map<char, std::vector<size_t>> buckets;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    buckets[arr[i]].push_back(i);
  }
  system("/bin/date +%s%M");
  return 0;
}
/*
152996960333
152996960733
So about 400 milliseconds
*/
```